# Draw polygon with hole inside

Tags: octave

I need to draw a rectangle polygon with a rectangle hole inside. I found this piece of code but I couldn't manage to understand how I can modify to meet my requirement.

```
 figure()
 p  = [0 0; 0 1; 1 1; 1 0]; %ccw
 pp = [0 0; 1 0; 1 1; 0 1]; %cw
 ph = p + [1.2 0];
 # add hole
 ph(end+1,:) = nan;
 ph = [ph; (pp-[0.5 0.5])*0.5+[1.7 0.5]];
 po = polygon2patch (ph);
 patch (po(:,1), po(:,2), 'b', 'facecolor', 'c');
 axis image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`polygon2patch`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/geometry/function/polygon2patch.html) function certainly seems useful, but maybe for only drawing two rectangles, you could also use just two [`patch`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/patch.html) commands, and simply set the inner rectangle, i.e. the hole, to white foreground color, like so:

```matlab
outer = [0 0; 2 0; 2 1; 0 1];
inner = [0.4 0.2; 1.6 0.2; 1.6 0.8; 0.4 0.8];
patch(outer(:, 1), outer(:, 2), 'c');
patch(inner(:, 1), inner(:, 2), 'w');
axis equal;
```

This will produce such an output:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!